# Treats for the cows - bottom up dynamic programming

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The full problem statement is [here](http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/TRT/). Suppose we have a double ended queue of known values. Each turn, we can take a value out of one or the other end and the values still in the queue increase as `value*turns`. The goal is to find maximum possible total value.

My [first approach](http://tny.cz/ad21161f) was to use straightforward top-down DP with memoization. Let `i`,`j` denote starting, ending indexes of "subarray" of array of values `A[]`.

```
                A[i]*age if i == j
f(i,j,age) =
                max(f(i+1,j,age+1) + A[i]*age , f(i,j-1,age+1) + A[j]*age)
```

This works, however, proves to be too slow, as there are superfluous stack calls. Iterative bottom-up should be faster.

Let `m[i][j]` be the maximum reachable value of the "subarray" of `A[]` with begin/end indexes `i`,`j`. Because `i <= j`, we care only about the lower triangular part.

This matrix can be built iteratively using the fact that `m[i][j] = max(m[i-1][j] + A[i]*age, m[i][j-1] + A[j]*age)`, where `age` is maximum on the diagonal (size of `A[]` and linearly decreases as `A.size()-(i-j)`.

My attempt at [implementation](http://tny.cz/8026a420) meets with [bus error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error).

Is the described algorithm correct? What is the cause for the bus error?

Here is the only part of the code where the bus error might occur:

```
for(T j = 0; j < num_of_treats; j++) {
    max_profit[j][j] = treats[j]*num_of_treats;
    for(T i = j+1; i < num_of_treats; i++)
        max_profit[i][j] = max( max_profit[i-1][j] + treats[i]*(num_of_treats-i+j),
                                max_profit[i][j-1] + treats[j]*(num_of_treats-i+j));
}
```

Comment: That looks like you should be easily able to solve it yourself by using a decent debugger and step through, before bothering the SO community!

Comment: Just as a little note, the following statements: "I don't see why would using a vector or dynamic allocation should help" and "I am using only half of it anyway" are interesting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have tried that of course. I wouldn't have asked if I could solve it without external help...

Comment: Declare the array `static` to get it out of the stack.

Comment: @leparlon You are right. Stupid, writing what comes to head. I deleted that part of the question, it didn't make sense.

Comment: @mirgee Make a concise [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then please, instead of posting confuse code snippets, that don't provide to make a self contained test case for your code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are testable parts of code in the links, there is really no way to make it smaller. It is minimal by nature...

Comment: This is not minimal, not by a long shot. Minimal would be something like this: This is a part of my code; It throws this error; Help? Usually, there is no need for historical data.

Comment: @mirgee if you have tried debugging and stepping, which line raised the bus error and what values were the indexes?  You must know this, since you have done your debugging, and it would be really useful for many SO cotributors to go through the same steps in parallel that  you already have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the OP supposedly already done some debugging but cannot be bothered to tell us what they found out.

Comment: @MartinJames I thought I hadn't found anything useful, but I had. I am sorry I bothered the community. I answered the question, but maybe I should delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bus error is caused by trying to access array via negative index when `j=0` and `i=1` as I should have noticed during the debugging. The algorithm is wrong as well. First, the relationship used to construct the `max_profit[][]` array should is

```
max_profit[i][j] = max( max_profit[i+1][j] + treats[i]*(num_of_treats-i+j),
                        max_profit[i][j-1] + treats[j]*(num_of_treats-i+j));
```

Second, the array must by filled diagonally, so that `max_profit[i+1][j]` and `max_profit[i][j-1]` is already computed with exception of the main diagonal.

Third, the data structure chosen is extremely inefficient. I am using only half of the space allocated for `max_profit[][]`. Plus, at each iteration, I only need the last computed diagonal. An array of size `num_of_treats` should suffice.

[Here](http://tny.cz/ec40e4ea) is a working code using this improved algorithm. I really like it. I even used bit operators for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

`for(T j = 0; j < num_of_treats; j++) {`

Inside this loop, `j` is clearly a valid index into the array `max_profit`. But you're not using just `j`.

Comment: And what is invalid about the other index I use, `i`?

Comment: @mirgee: Nothing wrong with `i`, as far as I could see. Mind you, the problem also seems to be present in your original math.

Comment: Would you mind deleting your answer so that I can delete this question?